# Display Color Wheel using CSS Sprite Technique

Tags: css, css-sprites, color-wheel

[image]

Provided the color wheel image how can we display it using CSS Sprites technique adding hover effects over the red, blue & yellow areas ?  Clicking on any color area should open respective links.